# Is there a way to end the asynchronous screen of webview2?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, webview2

I am going to make a video chat using webview2 in the wpf app.

However, since webview2 runs asynchronously, it recognizes that the user did not leave the server even if the window was closed.

I just make a button and when it's clicked,`Window.GetWindow(this).Close();`
I implemented this syntax to work and the user leaves the server.

However, webview2 is working in the background when the user exits without pressing the button in the wpf window.

Is there a way to exit webview2 in the background when exiting the window within wpf?

```css
public Webcam()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
protected override async void OnContentRendered(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnContentRendered(e);
    try
    {
        **var webView2Environment = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync();**
        await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(webView2Environment);
        webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate("ServerIP");
        string test = "JoinRoom(test)";

        webView.CoreWebView2.NavigationCompleted += CoreWebView2_NavigationCompleted;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {

    }
}
private void CoreWebView2_NavigationCompleted(object? sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            string test = "UserID";
            webView.CoreWebView2.PostWebMessageAsString(test);
        }
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string leaveroom = "leaveRoom";
            webView.CoreWebView2.PostWebMessageAsString(leaveroom);
            **Window.GetWindow(this).Close();**
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Closing the window in which WebView2 is hosted is not enough.

You will need to call [Dispose (see MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.wpf.webview2.dispose?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.864.35) on your instance of Webview2 so that it dealt with.

Answer (score 1):

considering you have webview2 tool in a UserControl tool you have to stop and dispose to kill each process automatically after finishing your task:

```
    public U_WebView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Disposed += U_WebView_Disposed;
    }
    private void U_WebView_Disposed(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webView21.Stop();
        webView21.Dispose();
    }
```